# Stokes theorem for non-compact case

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, stokes-theorem

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold and $D$ be a snc divisor on it. Then on $X\setminus D$ Stokes theorem holds true

$$\int_{X\setminus D}\Delta\alpha=0 ?$$

In this case $X\setminus D$ is non-compact, but we know of course $\int_{X }\Delta\alpha=0$

Comment: But $D$ is of measure zero, so $\int_D \Delta \alpha = 0$.

Comment: @JohnMa you mean $\int_{X\setminus D}\Delta\alpha+\int_{D}\Delta\alpha=\int_{X}\Delta\alpha $ and since $\int_D \Delta \alpha = 0$ hence we get the desired result. But how do you know that $D$ is of measure zero?